# Remove an extended permission using the PHP SDK / JavaScript SDK?

Tags: permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

in my app I want to allow the users to change the extended user permissions without going to the privacy settings page.

In the old REST API there is the "auth.revokeExtendedPermission" action to remove a specific permission, but I don't want to use this API because it will be depreciated soon.

Is there an other way to remove an extended permission using the newer PHP SDK or the JavaScript SDK?

Best
Flashbaer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [auth.revokeExtendedPermission documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeExtendedPermission/) the replacement for this in the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is a HTTP `DELETE` to `/{user id}/permissions?permission={permission name}`

This is covered here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions

Answer (score 0):

Example call to delete a permission:

$delete_success = $fb->api('/'.$fb->getUser().'/permissions?permission=create_event', 'DELETE');